# Python push script to background and call whenever required

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

I would like to put a python script, which accepts command line arguments, running in the background and call the script whenever required.

The reason is the script runs `nltk`, `spacy` and its many datasets and models which take a lot of time to initialize.

So I just want to initialize it once and call it whenever needed. I don't want to run a server either. Defeats the purpose of low overhead.

I found this [helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396654/how-to-run-the-python-program-in-the-background-in-ubuntu-machine) to put it in the background. But after that if I am calling the script `python run_service.py "arguments"`, it makes a separate call.
Or if I am doing `run_service.py "arguments"`, it says the command was not found.

This is the process

```
~/Desktop/python$ ps ax|grep ner.py
15552 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto ner.py
```

But I can't see it in the system monitor either.

Comment: "I don't want to run a server either." — "Server" in the sense of "an entire dedicated computer" or in the sense of "a daemon program"?  The latter's pretty much your only option.

Comment: simple HTTP server.

Comment: That didn't answer my question.  The word "server" has two different definitions: a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) or the computer it runs on.

Comment: You may use a lighter interface like unix named pipes, just rewrite your script to use stdin instead of arguments and attach it to pipes. See `man mkfifo`.

Comment: `mkfifo` don't work with `nohup`? [This example](http://timmurphy.org/2013/11/11/using-fifos-in-python/) breaks if run with `nohup` and terminal closed.